# Map function with array based on integers on 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```py
>>> a = 0.001 * np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(5))
>>> a
array([0.524, 0.311, 0.603, 0.957, 0.923])

>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(3, 5))
>>> b
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

I want to map over each row of the 2D array `b`, and if the value at row[i] == 1, set it to a[i], if the value at row[i] == 0, I want to set it to 1 - a[i].

For example, for `b[1] = row = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, it should become:

```
[1 - 0.524, 1 - 0.311, 0.603, 1 - 0.957, 1 - 0.923]
```

i.e.

```
[0.476, 0.689, 0.603, 0.043, 0.077]
```

How can I achieve this for all rows of the 2D matrix without resorting to for loops? (i.e. leverage efficiency of numpy)

Comment: What's the shape of the result supposed to be?  Show the full working iterative code.

Comment: `np.where(b.astype(bool), 1 - a, a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. I would probably use the `where` and `out` arguments to `np.subtract`:

```
np.subtract(np.ones(len(b)), a, out=np.broadcast_to(a, b.shape).copy(), where=b.astype(bool))
```

Going with @hpaulj's solution to use the 3-arg version of `np.where` is probably much cleaner in this case:

```
np.where(b, a, 1 - a)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get `non-broadcastable output operand with shape (5,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,5)` as an error, unfortunately, is there any way to perform it on a 2D array?

Comment: The `out` needs to be (3,5) the shape of `b`.  For example `a[None].repeat(3, axis=0)`

Comment: Here the `np.where` function is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @herophant. Sorry, I forgot to broadcast the ones correctly.